# Python shorthand for array limits

Tags: python, numpy

Given a `numpy` array:

```
a = arange(10,20,1)
```

I often need a tuple containing the first and last elements of the array:

```
w = a[0],a[-1]
```

Is there a handy python slicing shortcut to do this in a single reference to `a`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, use Numpy's *advanced indexing*:

```
w = a[[0, -1]]
```

Comment: @gnibbler: well, the question does start with "given a numpy array" :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want:

```
a[::len(a)-1]
```

This tells it to give you a slice from the beginning to the end, with the "step" value being one less than the length of the array (so take the first value, then take one which is `len(a)-1` indexes later, which is the last value).

It seems to work well in numpy:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.arange(10, 20, 1)
>>> a
array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19])
>>> a[::len(a)-1]
array([10, 19])
>>> tuple(a[::len(a)-1])
(10, 19)
```

Comment: I like how this one uses straight python slicing and doesn't require numpy

Answer (score 2):

You can easily make one

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> from numpy import arange
>>> a = arange(10,20,1)
>>> first_and_last = itemgetter(0, -1)
>>> first_and_last(a)
(10, 19)
```

Comment: `itemgetter` is cute.  This is certainly more verbose than nneonneo's answer but I wonder it will be more flexible for certain things?

Comment: It's the way to go if you have non-numpy sequences. But, Numpy's advanced indexing lets you do a lot more than just get indices; it lets you build entirely new arrays from sets of coordinate arrays.